# How can I return a NonNullable type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have code similar to the following:

```
interface Stuff {
  foo: number | null;
  bar: string | null;
}

let stuff: Stuff;

function getStuff(): Stuff;
function getStuff<K extends keyof Stuff>(key: K): NonNullable<Stuff[K]>;
function getStuff<K extends keyof Stuff>(key?: K): Stuff | NonNullable<Stuff[K]> {
  if (key == null)
    return stuff;

  const value = stuff[key];
  if (value == null)
    throw new Error(`${key} is null`);

  return value;
}


const myStuff = getStuff('foo');
```

Clearly, when you get to the last line of `getStuff`, `value` cannot be `null` or `undefined` there, but Typescript gives this error:

```
Type 'Stuff[K]' is not assignable to type 'Stuff | NonNullable<Stuff[K]>'.
  Type 'string | number | null' is not assignable to type 'Stuff | NonNullable<Stuff[K]>'.
    Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Stuff | NonNullable<Stuff[K]>'.
      Type 'Stuff[K]' is not assignable to type 'Stuff'.
        Type 'string | number | null' is not assignable to type 'Stuff'.
          Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Stuff'.(2322)
```

If I remove `NonNullable`, then it works correctly, but of course `myStuff` will then require a null check instead, which is what I'm trying to avoid here. I.e. I *know* `value` cannot be `null` here, but how do I properly let Typescript know that, without "cheating", e.g. via `return value!`?

---

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgK4xsg3gWAChlkYB7MgLmRAwFsAjaZAHxowBsOBuIkhuFGoBnMFFABzVuy69CAXyJEOEMMlFYY1dJrlEYGEAjDAyIZBNU7sACgCU2zNjkGjJsxatOYAHgDSyBAAHpAgACbCyADWEACeZDjWMAB8NjGx1H4OyAByZjmcHHAMKj5JANp+ALrJLobGpuaWYEn+gSEQ4ZHpCWjeqekA-JnZSdJ5IAVcxaUV1cl4fMjAOGlxyAC8GzIcdkskUKoYUOYazkrEyAhmosgAbnAcGCjbZzDl6VVyJCvINg9PF7bWhcPaXEhgAAWUDIAHcaBB4QBRKAwqA2AAGABJcOl5MtIiCOBi7N8SMglodMCd7o9nnJFIQLtcQLc6LExttmkkbABychkXmkohAA)

---

#### Solution based on accepted answer

Ended up adding the following util to our project, with the assertions and a helper type (so we can write `Null` instead of `null | undefined` a bunch of places in our code)

```
// util/null
type Null = null | undefined;

export default Null;

export function isNotNull<T>(value: T)
: value is NonNullable<T> {
  return value != null;
}

export function assertNotNull<T>(value: T, throwError: (value: T) => never)
: asserts value is NonNullable<T> {
  if (value == null) throwError(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just simply do type assertion - `return value as NonNullable<Stuff[K]>`, or introduce the custom type guard.

The issue you are facing is that TS is not narrowing your control flow null check to `NonNullable`, but by custom type guard you can force it. Consider:

```
// type guard narrows to NonNullable
function isNonNullable<T>(a: T): a is NonNullable<T> {
  return a !== null
}
function getStuff(): Stuff;
function getStuff<K extends keyof Stuff>(key: K): NonNullable<Stuff[K]>;
function getStuff<K extends keyof Stuff>(key?: K): Stuff | NonNullable<Stuff[K]> {
  if (key == null)
    return stuff;

  const value = stuff[key];
  if (isNonNullable(value)) {
    return value;
  }
  throw new Error(`${key} is null`);
}
```

Pay attention that `isNonNullable` is generic type-guard which you can use with any other value.

---

Reversed condition will also work correctly:

```
if (!isNonNullable(value)) {
  throw new Error(`${key} is null`);
}
return value;
```